# Get an image from two imageViews in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm developing an app where I have an area where there is an image in the background, and another image that I can move, like a sticker.

My goal is to create and save an image with the background image and the "sticker" above, using Swift. Here's my function that allows me to do what I want (my background view is called "imageView", my imageview sticker is called "jacques") :

```
    let newSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.image!.size.width, imageView.image!.size.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);

    imageView.image!.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height))

    let jacquesX = ((jacques.frame.origin.x - imageView.frame.origin.x) * (imageView.image?.size.width)!) / UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    let jacquesY = ((jacques.frame.origin.y - imageView.frame.origin.y) * (imageView.image?.size.height)!) / UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    let jacquesWidth: CGFloat = jacques.image!.size.width
    let jacquesHeight: CGFloat = jacques.image!.size.height       
    jacques.image!.drawInRect(CGRectMake(jacquesX, jacquesY, jacquesWidth, jacquesHeight))

    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
```

Unfortunately, my sticker isn't the right size. I think it's well placed in the image, but it's size is way too small. I don't know if my solution is the best one, i'm open to all suggestion. And I'm new, so if you have good practice to share, i'm all ears :)

Comment: Your code looks reasonable, but you say "my sticker isn't the right size." Only you know what the "right" size is. You need to state your goal if you want us to help you achieve it. If you draw out the two images on graph paper, what do you want them to look like? How big should the `jacques` image be on the `imageView` image? If you log the sizes of your `imageView` and your `jacques` image, are they the sizes that you want them to be? My guess is that your `jacques` is simply smaller than you expect it to be.

Comment: You still have not provided enough information for this to be a meaningful question. Please either close your question or provide a clear explanation of your goals, the sizes of the source images and their placement, and the size of the output. Otherwise this question is meaningless to everybody but you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in the storyboard. First you could size the picture however you want. To create a sticker effect you could just add imageView, size it to background size,and then put jacques on the storyboard, and finally resize them.